# Strange info message when executing 'emulator' from command line

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

```
~ Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -list-avds
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-me/emu-crash-34.1.18.db, detection is enabled for process: 1884
```

I get this message every time I execute emulator command with any arguments.
Also this line appears in Android Studio in dropdown list of emulators.
Version of "Android Emulator" displayed in SDK manager is 34.1.18.
I tried to remove sdk and install it again, also I tried to remove ~/.android folder - nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

The new emulator update includes this feature showing the saved crash data's location. This will be available in the latest versions of Android emulators.